# Amazon in-app purchasing on iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, in-app-purchase, login-with-amazon

I'm building a small app where users can browse cheap accessories like lipstick, nail polish, etc. I have Login With Amazon (http://login.amazon.com/) implemented because I originally thought that I could allow users to buy the accessories directly from my app.

But I soon realized that Apple has actually restricted that functionality. The purchase ability is available on Android and for web developers, but unfortunately not yet for iOS.

Is there some hacky way that I can allow users to make a purchase from my app (or from a web view in my app)?  I have a little bit of experience with Python so I'm guessing there might be a way to write a script that presses different buttons on the Amazon web page in a web view in my app. The user is already logged in with Amazon.

Comment: What is the actual problem?  You say they "restricted" the functionality.  You mean via policy or via code.  The policy does not apply to *physical* purchased items.

Comment: I guess I'm just a little confused as to how I should go about actually implementing purchase functionality - it seemed to me like a policy thing, but maybe I'm thinking of in-app purchasing vs. actual products, as you mention.

Comment: The policy is simple:  If it is used in your app (digitally) then you *must* use IAP.  If it is something else, you *must not* use IAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shopelia SDK which enables in-app purchase of physical goods using one click payment. It is available for Amazon but also for any kind of retailers.

It works using a combinaison of automation and monetics to inject the order and process the payment.

Right now (October 2013), the product is in beta stage and can be demonstrated on Shopelia website http://www.shopelia.com
Integration is available through SDK for Android and iOS.

Disclaimer : I'm co-founder of Shopelia. Please contact me if you are interested to integrate the technology in your app.